# Thread: how to bypass <intercept-url pattern="/trusted/**"

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, intercept

```
i have  a spring configuration,
i want to access <intercept-url pattern="/trusted/**"   filters = "none" />
```

without      filter
    is there any way to access
    i take this error when i use filters = "none"
    org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Config
    uration problem: The use of "filters='none'" is no longer supported. Please defi
    ne a separate  element for the pattern you want to exclude and use the att
    ribute "security='none'".|Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/
    spring-servlet.xml]

```
      <http  access-denied-page="/login.jsp" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
            <intercept-url pattern="/photos" access="ROLE_USER,SCOPE_READ" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/photos/**" access="ROLE_USER,SCOPE_READ" />
    <!--        <intercept-url pattern="/trusted/**" access="ROLE_USER,SCOPE_TRUST" />-->
             <intercept-url pattern="/trusted/**"   filters = "none" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/request_token_authorized.jsp" access="ROLE_USER,DENY_OAUTH" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY,DENY_OAUTH" />

            <form-login authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp" default-target-url="/index.jsp" login-page="/login.jsp"
                login-processing-url="/login.do" />
            <logout logout-success-url="/index.jsp" logout-url="/logout.do" />
            <anonymous />
            <custom-filter ref="oauth2ProviderFilter" after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER" />
        </http>
```

Comment: ı solved ıt using <intercept-url pattern="/trusted/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />  thıs :))successfull

Comment: you could post your own answer and accept it so others know this question is resolved

Comment: Property or field 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot'

Answer (score 6):

you need to add a extra http element:

```
<http pattern="/trusted/**" secure="none">
</http>
```